# how to set 2 types of user for a certain app

Tags: java, android, facebook, firebase-authentication

I wanna to create an app that has 2 types of users
first type is admin: that has Authority to add info and manage the app
second type is the customer
and every one has a different options and screens
now if I used firebase with specific login with facebook, it will offer only one type of user
so how I can use the both types of users authinication ( where I begin to search ?? )
and if want to put an IF method in the code of the app ( if the admin input a specific password it will give him the access to the admin app , is this method dangerous or less security ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

you can assign `custom claims` into user accounts, you should then use those `custom claims` as specified in the documentation to distinguish whether that user have the required `custom claims` 'rights) in order to make that specific action, be it read/write to firestore or to storage.

In the application you can use those custom claims to select which UI to display for the logged in user.

The UI in itself should be just a skeleton, you should always populate the UI with data from a trusted source (a server, firestore, storage, cloud functions) in order to verify the integrity of the `custom claims` as a malicious can edit your code to get access to the UI.